# How to switch a tag with its synonym?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed that [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) tag is a synonym of [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) so will be renamed to [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x). [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) name is quite outdated and will be never correct anymore. It's already 2011. Most probably the new standard will be approved this autumn. So rename it to an older name if [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) will be the correct one (with high probability)?

So I'd like to switch them: to make [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) a synonym of [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11). How do you do this? Where can I propose this switch?

EDIT:

standard is approved: http://herbsutter.com/2011/08/12/we-have-an-international-standard-c0x-is-unanimously-approved/

Edit: it seems these two have been disconnected now. There are 33 [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) questions and 1549 [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) questions. c++0x has been proposed as a synonym for c++11 but nobody has voted for it, and probably nobody can because they don't have tag rep in c++11. Sigh.

Comment: You do it here, just like you did basically.  :)  Though if the standard name isn't set just yet, I wouldn't carry it out yet.

Comment: `C++11` isn't set yet, right. But its probability is 90% or above. Probability of `C++x0` is alredy 0. The synonyms page says "The following tags will be remapped to `c++0x`", and list of one tag: `C++11`. Isn't it funny? It's exactly opposite to reality. Actually its `C++0x` will be renamed to `C++11`.

Comment: The problem with you C++ people is that **none of you can agree which tag name is correct**. Do a search here on Meta for all sorts of other counter-proposals, disagreements, and confused feature requests related to C++0x and the tag system...

Comment: actually the question was about any automated way to propose tag synonim change. [C++x0] is just an example, but completely shadowed the question.

Answer (score 3):

You do it here, just like you did basically, as a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question, tagged with the appropriate thing, in this case [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms)

I say right now inertia should win, and [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) has the inertia (and is the target of all of the synonyms).  Once there's an official name, change it to that.  Until that point, go with what is the most popular because it's not any more or less correct.

Comment: standard is approved: http://herbsutter.com/2011/08/12/we-have-an-international-standard-c0x-is-unanimously-approved/

Comment: you suggest "change it to that" when the question was "how to change"

Comment: I'll edit my comment on your question into my answer, because this is the way to do it - post here as a support post.

Answer (score 1):

I have been advocating strongly for us to continue to call it C++0x even while others were ready to go to C++11. But now the standard has been approved by all the countries, and it is no longer a draft standard, I think it's time to switch the synonyms. It really is C++11 now.

Scott Meyers: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2011/08/c11-feature-availability-spreadsheet.html

Herb Sutter: http://herbsutter.com/2011/08/12/we-have-an-international-standard-c0x-is-unanimously-approved/

Bjarne Stroustrup: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html
   (he's kind of on the fence still but does say it's called C++11, just that he doesn't feel like rewording his FAQ yet)

It's time.